# Interacting with R script via Python subprocess

Tags: python, r, subprocess

I was wondering how to open an R script and interact with it (for example, send strings, integers etc.). Although I have not used it before, subprocess seemed like a reasonable way to do this.

So far, I have

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['/path/to/Rscript --no-save path/to/script.R'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

This appears to be successful in opening script.R, however in my script I prompt the user to enter an integer and I cannot quite sort out how to do this.  I have tried:

```
process.communicate(input=1)[0]
```

But I appear to be barking up the wrong tree. The subprocess closes without appearing to receive this input.

EDIT: Rpy is probably not a good alternative at this point, because users of this script will not necessarily have access to that module and its dependencies.

Comment: what is the result of `process.communicate(input=1)`?

Comment: Right - good question, I should have specified that I see *no* visible output as a result of process.communicate(input=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try PypeR ?

It is an great interface to use R in python through pipe.

Comment: This was really useful, thanks.  I was able to send commands through to my scripts using this approach.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT2**

What about that?

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['/path/to/Rscript', '--no-save', 'path/to/script.R'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

**EDIT1**

You can only comunicate strings between processes over stdin and stdout.

Does `process.communicate("1\n")` help you out?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.   The string vs int distinction does not matter, because the process closes before the input can be passed.

Comment: Yes, that seems to help. I can now pipe strings to the subprocess via process.stdin.write('source("script.R")')   That's a step forward, thanks!